# increeasing static numbers within excel formulas when dragging formula down

Tags: excel

I have recently found on another website a formula which works perfectly for my requirements. However I have a slight issue (more of a time consuming thing then anything) when dragging the formula down through multiple rows I was wondering if there is a way to incrementally increase the static numbers?

this is the formula

```
=IF(AND(YEAR(MayOffset+1)=CalendarYear,MONTH(MayOffset+1)=5),MayOffset+1,"")
```

The bit I would like to automatically increase when dragging down is the "+1" after MayOffset. is it even possible to do this in any way other then manually altering it

Comment: put `+ROW(1:1)` in place of each `+1`.  As it is dragged down it will go from 1 to 2 to 3 to...

Comment: That worked perfectly, thanks very much

Comment: @ScottCraner You could in fact just use `+Row()`. Without arguments, it returns the row number of the cell it's in.

Comment: @JackDeeth and if the formula does not start in row 1?  By using `1:1` the first formula can be in any row.